# An infinite sum of products

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, infinite-product, exponential-sum

I have to calculate this sum in closed form

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{k-1}}{1 - x^k} $$

where $x < 1$.

Numerical evaluation shows that this converges. The product can be performed separately in the numerator and the denominator, but this doesn't seem to help. Any tip would be welcome.

Edit: Using the comment from TheBestMagician below, this becomes $ \sum_{n\geq1} \sum_{l_1 \geq 0} \sum_{l_2 \geq 0} \dots \sum_{l_n \geq 0} x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n \ k l_k} $. It is not obvious though how to sum it back.

Comment: Perhaps the expansion $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$ will be of use.

Comment: @TheBestMagician Using that, it becomes $ \sum_{n\geq1} \sum_{l_1 \geq 0} \sum_{l_2 \geq 0} \dots \sum_{l_n \geq 0} x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n \ k l_k} $. It is not obvious though how to sum it back.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a closed form in terms of ordinary functions. It is known that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{k-1}}{1 - x^k}=2\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n)-1$$
where $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n)$ is the generating function of the [number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts) (see also the formula section in [A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009) and [A087135](https://oeis.org/A087135)).